# What Android browsers have VPNs built in?

Tags: android, web-browser, privacy, vpn

I want an Android browser with a stable  solid VPN built-in, so that I don't need to install additional VPN client to my phone, like OpenVPN or VPN providers proprietary clients.

You call it web-proxy? Ok, whatever! I don't care how it is called and how it is implemented (SOCKS5 proxy, HTTPS or OpenVPN). I just want to open a page, type address and change my country on-the-fly.

Ideally it should support [fingerprint-spoofing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76945/how-to-fake-a-browser-fingerprint) (like in browsers [Linken Sphere](https://ls.tenebris.cc)
or [GoLogin/Orbits](https://gologin.com)), but let's keep it simple here and stick only to VPN feature. Unfortunately these no-fingerprint browsers have no Android version.

I tried [to search Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Browser%20with%20vpn&c=apps)
of course but none of them are trustworthy and high-rating apps, mostly no names. Maybe somebody already tried them and can share personal experience?

I searched [Software Recommendations S.E.](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+vpn+browser), but I found only three questions and none are relevant.

#### What have I tried myself so far?

1. Opera browser. Seems slow and luggish, VPN-connection is not always stable
2. Puffin Browser. A lot better experience, but also has some problems with site rendering and UX, and it's also buggy.
3. Tor Browser. Is blocked by many providers, so almost impossible to use, maybe I'm not experienced enough to set up it not be blocked.

**Budget**: I can pay one-time purchase, and even subscription, but not excessively, it shouldn't be $20 monthly.

**Other features**: I don't care. Only VPN needed, but it should be stable and not in the block list of Google and other providers.

Comment: If you want stable VPN which should not be in blocked lists then you would need to pay a bit since it costs providers to maintain good VPNs. For free VPNs, _you_ are likely to be the product. Fingerprint spoof/prevention is next to impossible on mobile devices for any serious purpose.

Comment: I am ready to pay, I put it in the bottom. How much? It depends

Comment: Fingerprint-spoofing is not reliable at all on Android. If you use custom ROMs then they themselves will make you stand out even more - which is bad for spoofing.VPNs, if they're reasonably priced will be abused by spammers within a day or two - so they'll be added to blacklists. Good ones cost upwards of $20 per month and they are mostly available only to verified customers (to avoid their IPs getting blacklisted).Bottom line is that you can get VPN on mobiles if you pay but you cannot spoof FP against serious companies. You MUST use a PC (hardened) for it to stand a chance.

Comment: Ok, I got you point about FP-spoofing. That's why I've put it as an optional feature, and main requirement which is in the title is reliable VPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a browser that address most of the my requirements, it is Epic Browser:

Site: [www.epicbrowser.com](http://www.epicbrowser.com)

Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.epic.browser&hl=en&gl=US

- it is free
- it is available for many platforms including Android
- it has VPN as a plugin to core functionality
- its VPN is not so dirty as many commercial VPNs I have and is not blocked on major sites

In Epic it is called proxy, which in fact is browser-based VPN that allows selecting from several server locations

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've used the Brave browser on my computer and love it! I found out they have a mobile browser with a VPN that I haven't used, but I know several people that love it. If you would like to try it, [here's a link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brave.browser&hl=en). Also, I'm not sure if it lets you change the country so I'd use the free trial to make sure.

See the Brave Help Center article: [How do I use the Built-in VPN + Firewall [Android]?](https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/4410838268429-How-do-I-use-the-Built-in-VPN-Firewall-Android-) for more information.

**Pricing**: $9.99 a month + free trial

Comment: I used Brave on mobile device for a little while and I didn't like it. Too much ads, too little stability. Also at the times I used it (2-3 years ago) it had no VPN onboard. Did you try their VPN feature on mobile? How it feels like?

Comment: It’s incompatible with my phone, but if it’s as great as their browser, it’ll be amazing.  The ads you were getting are an opt-in feature where you can get payed cryptocurrency to get the ads.  You can disable them at any time.  My brother uses Brave on mobile and he says it’s just as stable as Chrome now.

Comment: I checked their site and VPN version is available only on iOS, so it is not an option ;(

Comment: Oh dang, sorry I though it was for both.