# What Windows browsers have built in FREE VPNs? DISregard Epic, Opera, Tor

Tags: vpn

I need **browsers**, for **Windows** 10 and 11 desktops, built-in with a stable and solid **VPN**. I spurn installing an additional VPN client!

#### Rule out, AND DON'T REPEAT, the following that I already [tried](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/77165)!**

1. **Opera browser** is slow and sluggish. Its VPN connection can be unstable.
2. **Tor Browser** is blocked by many providers, so impossible to use.
3. **Epic browser** is downsizing its number of  VPN server locations. They halted their India server. I need sundry connections from as many different countries as possible!

#### Budget

I prefer FREE of charge! Please specify if each of your recommendation is FREE- or PAY-ware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> They halted their India server.

India now requires VPNs log user activity. All providers have pulled out of India, or are in the process of pulling out. India is no longer a safe place to put a VPN server.